# How can 32bit modules run on 64bit Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, 32bit-64bit

I wrote a genetic algorithm program using the inspyred library with a 32bit Python2.7 version on a 64bit Win7 machine. While generating the population the program stops running when it uses memory up to 1959044K.

I have read a number of questions on this site, and I understand that it is due to a 2GB cap on 32bit programs by the OS. So I have tried to switch to a 64bit Python and install the 64bit versions of the modules I was working with, unfortunately all but one module cannot run on the 64bit platform.

I also installed pywin32 as advised in another question but that has failed to help too. This module is not a standard Python library and I have pasted it below. The error message I get is:

```
import AoN
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

My understanding is that the 64bit Python does not recognize the 32bit module. I also read here: http://effbot.org/zone/python-compile.htm about compiling the source code, but I have compiled the source code in 64bit but that does not help either as it continues to give that error.

Lastly I pasted the directory path of the module in the interpreter path but that does not help too.

Is there a way to have this module run on the 64bit Python? 
And please can anyone explain the process of compiling source codes and if that can help me out?

Comment: Try grabbing (if you don't have it) Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition (which is free), install it, then go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC`, open a Command Prompt and type `vcvarsall amd64` to set the compiler to 64-bit mode. Then try to recompile your custom module and see if it works.

Comment: If the problem is that it can't import `AoN`, showing us this Python code won't help.  The Python code will run fine on either 64bit or 32bit as long as any C extension modules exist for the right version.  numpy and scipy are available for 64bit Python.  If AoN is a module you write in C, how did you compile it?

Comment: @BrenBram I have installed numpy and scipy 64bits as well. Still gets this error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is simple - it can't work. A process is either 32 or 64 bit, it's as simple as that. So if there is *one* module that can't run in 64 bit, one option besides re-compiling the module for 64 bit is to delegate whatever purpose it has to a second process running in 32 bit, just doing that. This might or might not be practical, depending on the actual task of the module.